# Azure Translator Text API: What is the definition of a character?

Tags: microsoft-translator

The pricing of the Translator Text API belonging to the Azure Cognitive Services family is based on characters.

But what is the definition of a character?

Some examples:

- Do spaces, punctuation and line breaks count as a character?

```
This is   ,   a     


test.
```

- When translating HTML does every character count here including angle brackets, tags, slashes etc.?

```
<p>This is<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a
test.</p>
```

For the sake of completeness: I suppose only the text that is being sent to the API for translation counts (request characters) and not what comes back (response), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered here [character counts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Translator/character-counts). All of the above examples count as text. Responses do not count.
Copying from there:

What counts is:

- Text passed to the Translator Text API in the body of the request
- Text when using the Translate, Transliterate, and Dictionary Lookup methods
- Text and Translation when using the Dictionary Examples method
- All markup: HTML, XML tags, etc. within the text field of the request body. JSON notation used to build the request (for instance "Text:") is not counted.
- An individual letter
- Punctuation
- A space, tab, markup, and any kind of white space character
- Every code point defined in Unicode
- A repeated translation, even if you have translated the same text previously

Comment: Thank you. :) Finding stuff in structures is hard... ;)